# Can't retrieve user un AuthGuard but in Decorator in NestJS

Tags: typescript, routes, graphql, nestjs, guard

I implemented a `Graphql` API in NestJS with a guard to prevent some roles to access given routes. So far I'm able to retrieve the user in the `CurrentUser` decorator through `GQLExecutionContext`. But not in the Guard.

Below is the guard:

```js
  import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

  @Injectable()
  export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

    canActivate(
      context: ExecutionContext,
    ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
      const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
      if (!roles) {
        return true;
      }
      const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
      console.log('adminguard', ctx.getContext().req.user);
      const request = ctx.getContext().req;
      const user = request.user;
      return roles.includes(user?.role);
    }
  }
```

and here is the Decorator:

```js
  import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

  export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
   (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
      const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
      console.log('current user', ctx.getContext().req.user);
      return ctx.getContext().req.user;
    },
  );
```

All together:

```js
@Resolver(() => User)
export class UsersResolver {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Roles('admin')
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
  @Query(() => [User], { name: 'users' })
  findAll(@CurrentUser() user: User) {
    return this.usersService.findAll();
  }
}
```

My app module implements `Graphql` like so:

```js
   GraphQLModule.forRoot({
     autoSchemaFile: './schema.gql',
     context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
     debug: true,
     playground: true,
   }),
```

I want to be able to retrieve the user in the AdminGuard the same way I do with the decorator. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was to think that `@Roles('admin')` was invoking my `AdminGuard` under the hood.
To fix the code, I renamed `AdminGuard` to `RolesGuard`. Then I fixed the implementation like so:

```js
  @Roles(['admin']) // 1. first define authorized role
  @UseGuards(RolesGuard) // 2. then bind RolesGuard
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard) // 3. finally use the GqlAuthGuard
  @Query(() => [User], { name: 'users' })
  findAll(@CurrentUser() user: User) {
    return this.usersService.findAll();
  }
```